# how to check my questions that have not been answered?

Tags: support, questions, accepted-answer

Hi all, is there anyway we can check the questions that we make that we have not marked any answers? (like a filter)

Which section should these questions be at?

Comment: Yeah, voted to move this to meta.SU - but @pacerier I don't think I understand your question.

Comment: @slhck i mean say i have asked 10 questions and accepted 9 answers. How do i search for that last question which i've not accepted an answer?\

Comment: @boehj yep accepting answers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Searching for

```
user:me hasaccepted:0
```

will bring up a list of your questions that don't have accepted answers.

http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/-887719788.png

Refer to [Search page](https://superuser.com/search) for more such options. Questions regarding Super User should be posted on [Meta.Super User](http://meta.superuser.com)

http://fhc.quickmediasolutions.com/image/-887795581.png

Answer (score 2):

go to your profile page

- https://superuser.com/users/78897/pacerier

and check your question section:

- unanswered questions have 0 answers
- accepted answers have a green background

was it this what you where asking for?

**Note:** For general unanswered questions use the [**Unanswered**](https://superuser.com/unanswered) link on the top of the page.

Comment: its something like this, but is there a filter which show me all the questions that do not have a green background? (or else i would have to manually scroll through the pages to find them.. i mean i can manually scroll through the pages now, but its not scalable at all)

Comment: no, not that I know of. unfortunately you have to visually check your questions.

Comment: refer to my answer

Comment: nice feature :)